# how to add description to each node of linked list in C language

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

So I have built a linked list but I want to add description to each node created in the output. The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Structure to create Linked list
typedef struct iorb {
int base_pri;
struct iorb *link;
char filler[100];
} IORB;

IORB * Build_list(int n);
void displaylist(IORB * head);

int main(){
int n=0;
IORB * HEAD = NULL;
printf("\nHow many blocks you want to store: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
HEAD = Build_list(n);
displaylist(HEAD);

return 0;
}

IORB * Build_list(int n){
int i=0;

IORB*head=NULL; //address of first block
IORB*temp=NULL; //temporary variable used to create individual block
IORB*p=NULL;    // used to add the block at the right position

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        //individual block is created

    temp = (IORB*)malloc(sizeof(IORB));
    temp->base_pri = rand() % 10;         //random values are generated to 
   be stored in IORB blocks
    temp->link = NULL;                    //Next link is equal to NULL

    if(head == NULL){            //If list is empty then make temp as the 
   first block
        head = temp;
    }
    else{
        p = head;
        while(p->link != NULL)
            p = p->link;
            p->link = temp;
    }
}

return head;
}

void displaylist(IORB * head){

IORB * p = head;
printf("\nData entered for all the blocks:\n");

while(p != NULL)
{
printf("\t%d", p->base_pri);
p = p->link;
}
}
```

So, the array "filler[100]" is to be used to give the description. To give a better idea I want the description to be like this:

Data for block 1 is 3

Data for block 2 is 0

Data for block 3 is 9

Data for block 4 is 7

Data for block 5 is 4

Where 3,0,9,7,4 are randomly generated values.

Comment: You can make your code more efficient O(N) by having a variable for the last element and link this to temp. This saves on doing the recursion that makes it O(N^2)

Comment: If your question can be simplified to "How can I store a short text in a structure?" then please do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can format a string with `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(temp->filler, sizeof temp->filler, "Data for block %d is %d", i, temp->base_pri);
```